# Rails: Invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (Argument Error) when I run rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, seeding, argument-error

When I run `rake db:seed` in my `Rails` app, I'm getting this error:

> invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (Argument Error)

I just added `science_majors` and down to my seed file, and now when I run `rake db:seed` it gives me this error:

> invalid byte sequence error

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

part of **seeds.rb**

```
@college = College.find_or_create_by_name!('University of Pittsburgh')
if @college.update_attributes(
  url: 'university-of-pittsburgh',
  public: 'Public',
  years: '4-year',
  category: 'National University',
  calendar: 'Semester',
  location: 'Pittsburgh, PA',
  setting: 'Large City (250-500k)',
  retention: '90',
  majors: 'business/marketing: 15%|social sciences: 14%|health professions: 11%|english: 10%|engineering: 9%|psychology: 8%|biology: 7%|history: 5%',
  scholarships_link: 'http://www.oafa.pitt.edu/universityschlrs.aspx',
  map: '<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.444261,-79.970448&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.431368,-79.9805&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=university+of+pittsburgh&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>',
  street_view: '<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=uni&amp;sll=40.444261,-79.970448&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;t=m&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=40.441775,-79.956671&amp;panoid=BgWQKMiSI1fpwP7JUF16Vg&amp;cbp=12,45.25,,0,-3.34&amp;output=svembed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=uni&amp;sll=40.431368,-79.9805&amp;sspn=0.142165,0.251656&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=University+of+Pittsburgh,+4200+Fifth+Ave,+Pittsburgh,+PA&amp;ll=40.443486,-79.958245&amp;spn=0.010798,0.021038&amp;t=m&amp;layer=c&amp;cbll=40.441775,-79.956671&amp;panoid=BgWQKMiSI1fpwP7JUF16Vg&amp;cbp=12,45.25,,0,-3.34" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>',
  housing: '<iframe src="http://www.tour.pitt.edu/tour-categories/residence-halls" scrolling="no" height="820" width="900"></iframe>',
  food: '<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 1000px;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.pc.pitt.edu/dining/menus.php" style="margin-left: 0; height: 2000px; margin-top: -370px; margin-bottom: -375px; width: 750px;"></iframe></div>',
  weather: '<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 500px;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.weather.com/weather/wxclimatology/monthly/graph/USPA1290" style="margin-left: -40px; height: 1570px; margin-top: -490px; width: 500px;"></iframe></div>',
  dorms: 'Towers (fr.)|Sutherland (fr.)|Lothrop (fr.)|Nordenberg (fr.)|Holland (fr.)|Forbes (fr.; honors)|McCormick|Brackenridge|Amos|Bruce|Panther|Pennsylvania|Ruskin|Bouquet Gardens|Oakwood Apartments|Centre-Plaza Apartments|Forbes-Craig Apartments (honors)',
  science_majors: 'Actuarial Mathematics|Applied Mathematics|Bioinformatics|Biological Sciences|Chemistry*|Computer Science|Ecology and Evolution|Environmental Geology|Environmental Studies|Geology|History and Philosophy of Science|Linguistics*|Mathematics*|Mathematics-Economics|Mathematics-Philosophy|Microbiology|Molecular Biology|Natural Sciences Area|Neuroscience*|Physics*|Physics and Astronomy|Scientific Computing|Statistics',
  social_science_majors: 'Economics*|Economics–Statistics|History*|Political Science*|Politics-Philosophy|Psychology|Sociology*|Urban Studies',
  humanities_majors: 'Africana Studies*|Africana Studies–English|Anthropology|Chinese*|Classics*|English Literature*|English Writing|Film Studies*|French*|German|History of Art & Architecture|Humanities Area|Italian*|Italian Studies|Japanese*|Liberal Studies|Music*|Philosophy*|Religious Studies*|Russian|Slavic Studies|Spanish|Studio Arts*|Theatre Arts*',
  business_majors: 'Accounting|Finance|General Management|Global Management|Marketing',
  engineering_majors: 'Bioengineering*|Chemical Engineering*|Civil Engineering*|Computer Engineering|Electrical Engineering*|Engineering Physics|Industrial Engineering*|Materials Science and Engineering*|Mechanical Engineering*',
  professional_majors: 'Administration of Justice*|Applied Developmental Psychology|Architectural Studies|Athletic Training|Clinical Dietetics and Nutrition|Communication: Rhet & Comm|Communication Science|Dental Hygiene|Emergency Medicine|Health Information Management|Health Services|Health and Physical Activity|Information Science|Legal Studies*|Media and Professional Communications|Nursing|Pharmacy|Public Service*|Rehabilitation Science|Social Work*'
)
else
  # handle validation errors
end

@college= College.find_or_create_by_name!('Harvard')
if @college.update_attributes(
  url: 'harvard',
  public: 'Private',
  years: '4-year',
  category: 'National University',
  calendar: 'Semester',
  location: 'Cambridge, MA',
  setting: 'Small City (50-250k)',
  degrees: 'Bachelors, Masters, Doctoral',
  rotc: 'Air Force, Army, Navy',
  considered: 'Academic GPA|Alumni Relation|Application Essay|Character/Personal Qualities|Extracurricular Activities|First Generation College Student|Geographical Residence|Interview|Racial/Ethnic Status|Recommendations|Rigor of secondary school record|Standardized Test Scores|Talent/Ability|Volunteer Work|Work Experience',
  student_faculty: '7 to 1')
else
  # handle validation errors
end
```

I left out all the other colleges. I have 200 schools so far, but Pitt is the only one with comprehensive data so far.  The rest just have basic data, like Harvard.  I also left out some of the data for Pitt for the sake of brevity, but let me know if you'd like me to include the rest.

Edit: I tried taking out the `*`'s in `science_majors` on down and then running `rake db:seed`, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You're receiving an encoding error because your filesystem isn't configured to encode the date you've added (since presumably it includes new characters – possibly in your HTML entity encoded map URL – that didn't exist in your prior data seed).

The following will should resolve this error by setting the UTF-8 locale on your machine:

```
# from your command line
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
bundle
```

The benefit of setting a system locale is that all gems (going forward) will be bundled using UTF-8 encoding.

EDIT:

Alternatively, if you don't want to change your system encoding, you can set your encoding project-wide by specifying an encoding standard in your Gemfile:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/ # assuming you're running Ruby ~1.9
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you take this approach, make sure that all environments that you've deployed your project to have their locales set to UTF-8. Otherwise, you'll need to add `#encoding utf-8` to the top of your file to ensure that it's properly encoded, as the other poster astutely notes.

Comment: i actually just tried to remove #encoding utf-8 and do what you said but it didn't work.

    `~/collegeanswers >>  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
    ~/collegeanswers >>  export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"  
    ~/collegeanswers >>  bundle  
    Using rake (10.0.4)  
    .  
    .  
    Using i18n (0.6.1)  
    Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.  
    ~/collegeanswers >>  rake db:seed  
    rake aborted!`  
  
do you know why?

Comment: What is your `rake` error? Your existing gems are probably not configured to work with your filesystem encoding yet. Try `bbundle exec gem uninstall i18n`, then `bundle install`.

Comment: my rake error was `invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
`.  I just tried what you said and got the same error.

Comment: Did you restart your webserver? Updated my answer to provide more options for accomplishing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  I've been doing control+c to go back and forth between rails s though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31547/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-zeantsoi)

Comment: Put this in your ~/.bash_profile instead (or appropriate file depending on your setup). Also change the en_US part depending on your language('en' here) and region ('US' here).

Answer (score 66):

Add

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

at the top of the file

Comment: Why do I need to do that now, but before I didn't have to?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked btw, so thanks! But I'd still like to know why everything was working before, and now I need to add that for it to work.

Comment: Maybe you added some special utf-8 signs in your file.. :)

Comment: I just read through the updates to the other guy's answer and it is actually more comprehensive so I'm gonna mark that as the accepted answer, but I still really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 41):

You can also try `export RUBYOPT="-KU -E utf-8:utf-8"`
as mentioned in this [GH thread](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/144)

Comment: Thanks! That's the only thing that helped with ```shotgun-0.9.1/bin/shotgun:94:in `[]': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)```

Answer (score 22):

If you are having this problem in a ruby docker container you might either set `LANG=C.UTF-8`:

```
docker run -it --rm -e LANG=C.UTF-8 ruby ...
```

or [watch this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/45).

Comment: or as seen in the link in this answer, if creating your own Docker image, add 'ENV LANG=C.UTF-8' to your Dockerfile

Answer (score 7):

Like others suggested, I added `#encoding: utf-8` to the top of my (in this case, seed.rb) file, but still couldn't get the rake task to work.

Interestingly enough, a friend recommended that I remove the additional, rails-generated comments from the top of the seed file so that only `#encoding: utf-8` remained.

What would you know - it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a invalid character in your seed file, in my case changing single quotes from ` to '  worked out.