# Cant run db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I trying to deploy my rails 4 application on my ubuntu server, if I run the rake db:migrate command I getting this error

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

My environment:

Rails 4.1.6
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

here the trace

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:395:in `glob'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:395:in `glob'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:258:in `block in have_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:256:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:256:in `have_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:657:in `find_rakefile_location'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:673:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

On my local machine everything works fine...

Comment: Maybe setting the UTF-locale like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031651/invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-argument-error-when-i-run-rake-dbseed-in-ra ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the data store being used here out of curiosity?  Is it possible to just destroy the database and start fresh by chance?  If so, you can do that with:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: this works, I think there where some bad data in the database