# EEXIST - File exists workspace/Pods

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods

This is occurring When I am trying to build the application through Jenkins.
I have wiped out the current workspace in Jenkins and build the application and its throwing the following error

````
[workspace] $ touch Pods rm -r -f Pods pod repo update
[workspace] $ pod install
[33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[0m

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 0.37.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
       Xcode : 6.3.2 (6D2105)
         Git : git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ efe0250cfcdd610a45cdd5691bd3c6bcb38669be
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-plugins : 0.4.2
cocoapods-trunk   : 0.6.1
cocoapods-try     : 0.4.5
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.2'
pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.3'
```

### Error

```
Errno::EEXIST - File exists - /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/App-iOS-Trunk/workspace/Pods
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/sandbox.rb:58:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:202:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:202:in `sandbox'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:69:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.2/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=File+exists+-+%2FUsers%2Fjenkins%2F.jenkins%2Fjobs%2FeLearner-Native-iOS-Trunk%2Fworkspace%2FPods&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Build step 'Update CocoaPods' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
````

For other applications for which current workspace is not not wiped are build gets successful. But when I wipe out the current workspace Its displaying the above Error.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in an "Execute shell" script before invoking `pod` fixed this on my Jenkins box.  Also consider using `-d` to check the directory.

```
# Cocoapods
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
if [ -d Pods ]; then    
    rm -rf Pods
fi
pod repo update
pod install
# ...
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Any other solution? Mine is for Cocoapods1.0.1

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha are you getting a different error than the one in the original question?

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha updated my answer with additional exports that might fix your problem.

Comment: I am getting this error
 /usr/local/bin/pod repo update
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/pod

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha change `/usr/local/bin/pod` to just `pod`.

Comment: Sure buddy will do that as soon as I am allowed. :)

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem here ?

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha sure, in your particular case your file system's text encoding format did not match the required UTF-8 format for Cocoapods.  The issue can be found with ruby/rails.  You can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17031651/2415822).